# No known class method for selector 'indexPathForCell:'

Tags: ios, uitableview

I dont understand what I have done wrong.

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [[self tableView] reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddTest"])
    {
        Model *newShots = [[testStore sharedTestStore] createTest];
        testViewController *newShotViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        [newShotViewController setCurrentScore:newShots];
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailTest"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [UITableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        Model *course = [[[testStore sharedTestStore] allTests] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        detailTestViewController *viewCourseController = segue.destinationViewController;
        [viewCourseController setCurrentScore:course];
    }
}
```

Its giving me an error of

> no know class method of indexPath for cell

in the line:

`NSIndexPath *indexPath = [UITableView indexPathforCell:sender];`

Not sure what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexPathForCell:` isn't a class method on `UITableView`. It is an instance method, meaning you need to call indexPathForCell: on your instance of `UITableView`, judging from your code, this will be `self.tableView`.

See the documentation for more information, [UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW12).